# Jio sim unable to call

Tags: sim-card

[image] I have this key sign showing near my Signal tower. In my phone screen and I can't make call please help me

Comment: This Key icon in the notification bar may be related to some VPN app that you are using. It is not related to network, you should contact Jio store as it is an ISP related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your phone supports VOLTE. The key sign has nothing to do with calling. The Jio4GVoice App cwn be used to call through the jio sim (if VOLTE is not supported).